# Elastic access runtime field in nested script query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I try to access a runtime field defined in my elastic query in a filter script query inside a nested structure.

I define the runtime field in my elastic query like this:

```
...
"runtime_mappings": {
    "my_runtime_field": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": "..."
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Then in the search query I would like to use it in a filter inside a nested structure:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['nested__objects.someField'] == my_runtime_field"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "nested__objects"
          }
        },
...
```

Is this possible? I tried different ways of accessing it and always got errors. I also tried to pass it as a param, without success.
I'm using Elastic 7.16.2

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this IS possible if you include "inner_hits" in your "nested" object. You can find their docs on this here: [ElasticSearch Retrieve Inner Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#2a91e1fb8ad93a188fa9d77ec01bc431)

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nested__objects",
            "inner_hits": {},
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['nested__objects.someField'] == my_runtime_field"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
...
```